# using regex on struts error messages in jsp page

Tags: regex, jsp, struts

I have error messages( inActionMessages) coming from server to jsp in some format which are displayed on jsp page using HTML Table and Rows.

I have a need to split each error message string into 2 strings with a given delimiter so that can be rendered in two different columns.

I have all the messages in struts ActionMessages. Is there any way i can use regex on each error and split into two and render both separately on jsp itself or if there is other solution?
Example Errors messages are :
(101) Name not valid
(102) Age can not be alphabetic. and i need to split each error into '101' and 'Name not valid' format.

Comment: Is format of all messages is similar to this format "(number) error text"?

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.split:()`:

```
String str = str.replaceAll("^\\( *", "");
String[] errors = str.split(" *\\( *");
for (String error : errors) {
    String[] parts = error.split(" *\\) *");
    String number = parts[0];
    String text = parts[1];
    // do something with number and text
}
```